# How to detect touch on colliders for a line renderer added manually in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have added a capsule collider for line renderer manually by instantiating it around the line.I am already adding different sprites to this scene.I detect the touch on top of these sprites by using **Physics2D Raycaster** on the Main Camera and in the script with the help of **IPointerEnterHandler** and them into the required gameObject containing  the sprite renderer.Sample code given below

[image: 3d Collider added]

```
 public class TouchDetect:MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler,IPointerExitHandler
    {

     public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
      {
        if (eventData.pointerEnter.gameObject.name == "redcircle2(Clone)" )
            {
                sound[1].source.clip = sound[1].clip;
                sound[1].source.loop = true;
                sound[1].source.Play();
            }
       }

    }
```

The capsule collider I have added is 3d collider.How to detect the touch on top of the collider along with the 2d colliders?

I have tried the below code but not working.

```
     if (Input.touchCount > 0 || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
      {
       Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
       bool collided = this.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().bounds.Contains(mousePos);




                if (collided)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touched collider " );
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Not collided");
                }
    }
```

Comment: For 3D colliders you need a `PhysicsRaycaster` but you seem to only have a `Physics2DRaycaster` which only works for 2D colliders.

Comment: Yes that was the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity there are 2 completely different and separated physics systems - `Physics`(3D) and `Physics2D`.

As said they are separated and don't interact in any way so that e.g. a `Collider` will never track any collisions with a `Collider2D`.

The same applies to the `PhysicsRaycaster` and `PhysicsRaycaster2D`!

In your Scene you have a `CapsuleCollider` which is a 3D collider.

It can only be tracked by using a `PhysicsRaycaster` - **not** by a `PhysicsRaycaster2D`!

→ Either your `Camera` should have a `PhysicsRaycaster` instead of a `PhysicsRaycaster 2D` or if it is supposed to be a 2D game anyway you should only use 2D colliders.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (eventData.pointerEnter.gameObject.name == "redcircle2(Clone)")
```

I am pretty sure this line is where the error comes from.
If you are instantiating, then I am going to take a guess you are instantiating from a public Transform and into that you have put some Prefab with already added collision, right?
Then check what gametag THAT PREFAB you have added has and detect that, not `"redcircle2(Clone)"`.